# Expansion Using Multinomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation

I was hoping someone could help me find an analytic expression for the $x^{2k}$ term of

$$\bigg(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\bigg)^{2g-2} = \big(1-\frac{x^{2}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{5!} + \ldots\big)^{2g-2}$$

for $g>0$.  I was trying to apply the multinomial theorem,

$$(x_{1} + \ldots + x_{m})^{2g-2} = \sum_{k_{1} + \ldots + k_{m}=2g-2} \binom{2g-2}{k_{1}, \ldots, k_{m}} \prod_{t=1}^{m} x_{t}^{k_{t}}$$

But in applying the multinomial theorem in my case, I have to be careful because there's many ways I can achieve a term like, say, $x^{8}$, as opposed to if $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}$ are symbolically distinct.  Can someone help me out here, or let me know of a better way to go about this sort of formula manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the **bi**nomial theorem, since $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$. In particular:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{2m} &=& \sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}(-1)^ke^{kix}e^{(k-2m)ix}\\&=&(-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}+2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{2m}{k}(-1)^k\cos((2m-2k)x)\end{eqnarray*}$$
and for every $h\geq 1$:
$$[x^{2h}](e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{2m} = \frac{2(-1)^h}{(2h)!}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{2m}{k}(-1)^k(2m-2k)^{2h}.$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot :)  Didn't think to try this.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco: glad to help, you're welcome.

Comment: There's something a little bizarre here.  Your derivation makes perfect sense, but if you recall my OP, I ultimately want to divide by $x^{2m}$.  This should be an easy add from your idea here.  However, $(\sin(x)/x)^{2m}$ has no negative powers of $x$.  Yet, above you have a constant term as well as low powers of $x$ from the cosine.  So when I divide by $x^{2m}$ I'm gonna get negative powers.  What is going on here?  I'm overlooking something simple I think.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco: the coefficient of $x^{2k}$ in $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2g-2}$ is related with the coefficient of $x^{2k\color{red}{+}2g-2}$ in $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{2g-2}$. No negative powers.

Comment: You're right of course, I was being dumb; thank you!  I apologize, but just one finicky point...you're very first equation should have a $(-1)^{k}$ when applying the binomial theorem, thanks to the minus sign on the lefthand side, correct?

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco: of course, I am going to fix it.